# Is $\ 2\ 377\ 271\ $ the smallest number giving the desired twin prime pair?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, twin-primes

I searched a twin prime of the form $$k\cdot 2023!\pm1$$ with positive integer $k$ as a project related to the current year. User hardmath claimed to have checked the range upto $k=2\ 200\ 000$ with no result. I accidently found out that $$k=2\ 377\ 271$$ gives a twin-prime pair, not with brute force , but with random trials.

> Is this the smallest $k$ giving the desired twin-prime pair ?

According to hardmath , this is the only $k$ upto $2.8\cdot 10^6$. I suggested in a chat to answer here , but so far without a reply. So, apart from a doublecheck (which is still appreciated) , this question is solved. I keep waiting for an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching up to $k=10^7$ in about 5 hours (using my own program and PFGW) I have found that the following values for $k$ result in a twin prime:

```
2377271
3069575
4480120
4728843
5292819
5547303
5966009
6131148
6307735
8849046
8980424
9181113
```

That means that I too have found no such $k < 2377271$. All the above values for $k$ are verified by PFGW to result in a twin prime.
For all other values $k < 10^7$ one of the two numbers was factored or one of the two was no 3-PRP according to PFGW.

Answer (score 1):

I've repeated the search for smallest $k$ such that $(2023!*k)\pm 1$ is a twin prime pair. I found $k=2377271$ both times.

Some minor changes in the second search are as follows:

- Platform:  Running [OpenPFGW](https://sourceforge.net/projects/openpfgw/) on Windows 10 vs. PFGW on Linux.
- Script Input:  The software in both cases is a commandline interface taking directions from a structured text input file.  In the new search I test first for $(2023!*k) + 1$ to be a ([3-probable](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2872406/what-does-3-prp-means-exactly-in-pfgw-primality-test)) prime and second for $(2023!*k) - 1$ to be a (3-probable) prime (the earlier search tested these in the opposite order).
- Machine:  The newer search was done on an AMD Ryzen 7 based laptop (which did each candidate in approximately 0.2 seconds), while the older search was done on an Intel Core i5 based desktop (which did each candidate in about 0.5 seconds).

It seems clear there are no prime pairs below $k=2377271$, but one might reasonably want additional testing for primality of the pair given by this $k$.  The [Apertron integer factorization calculator](https://www.alpertron.com.ar/ECM.HTM) (Web-assembly version) confirms primality by application of the BPSW test (of both numbers), essentially pairing a 2-probable prime calculation with a strong Lucas check.  These last two computations were done on yet a third PC (a Dell business class laptop).

Comment: If the 3-PRP test is not passed , it is sure that the given number is composite. Finding a prime factor of one of the numbers in every case will probably not work in practice.

Comment: factordb screens the primes $2023!\cdot 2377271\pm 1$ as proven primes , so if the p-1 and the p+1 test worked correctly, the numbers are indeed prime.